# Azure CORS Not working after configured

Tags: azure, cors

As a learning exercise I have created an Azure mobile service, added a very similar implementation to their TODO list example. I have deployed to Azure and configured the allowed origin (to an MVC site that I have also deployed to azure):

http://mr-mob-html-test.azurewebsites.net

I have re-started the service and try * as suggested by the configuration screen, however I keep getting this issue (which I am sure is CORS related):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mr-todolist-dotnet.azure-mobile.net/tables/EventItem. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://mr-mob-html-test.azurewebsites.net'` is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem in case someone happens to have the same issue.

I was testing the mobile service in my machine and modified the web.config adding a couple of origins for my localhost, I guess this was interfering with the configuration in the portal. I just added the new origin to the Web.config and re-published it:

I haven't tried removing this configuration and only trying with the configuration through the portal.

Anyway I hope this helps.